# Best way to move html content from .js file to .html file - completed

Tags: javascript, html

I have links such that when the user clicks on them, the DOM is quckly updated using the methods below.

Basically, I just set the innerHTML document to the text and the page updates.

However I would like html code with other html code when applicable.  This is the only place in my .js file that has a significant amount of text.  How do I move this?

```
/*
link - quick dom links - would like to find a way to move this into xhtml where it belongs
*/

function o2(a,b)
  {
  return document.getElementById(a).innerHTML=b;
  }

function l1()
  {
   ........
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend putting all of the possible HTML into your HTML file. Assign a unique id to each element and use CSS to hide them all or all but one by default (using 'display: none').  Then your javascript function can simply change CSS based on which html fragment you need to be visible.

Comment: This is how I should have done it.  I'm familar with CSS hidden.  But hidden elements still take up space...do I have to use relative positioning and offset each <p> tag so that they all sit in the same space?

Comment: No need for positioning, use `display: none` as suggested in the answer. It won't take up any space that way.

Comment: To make it a little more accessible to those who don't have JS, make everything visible by default and then hide the ones you don't want to show using JS when the DOM is ready.  Most DOM libraries provide a way of executing JS after the DOM is ready but before the rest of the page loads.  jQuery has a `.ready()` method for instance. Or if you prefer not to use a library, you could use the [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko-Specific_DOM_Events#DOMContentLoaded) event.